# .innerhtml not updating value immediately

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am using these two functions where in the first one I am updating the value of an innerhtml whilst in the second function I am taking the 'new' modified value in order to re-calculate the sub-total.

However, when taking the modified innerhtml in the second function, it is using the old value. It seems like innerhtml in the first function is not being updated immediately. I tried using setTimeout() to update immediately but it didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshTotal(ProductId) {
        var qty = document.getElementById("product-quantity-" + ProductId).value;
        var UnitPrice = document.getElementById("unit-price-" + ProductId).innerText;
        var total = qty * UnitPrice;
        $.get('@Url.Action("getItemPositionCart","Home")' , {id: ProductId}, function(data) //data - holds the data returned by the action
        {
            document.getElementById("product-total-" + data).innerHTML = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
            setTimeout(performExpensiveCalculationsAndRender(), 0);
        });

        $.post('@Url.Action("EditQuantity", "Home")', { id: ProductId, quantity: qty }, function (data) {

        }) 

        updateTotal.call();
    }

    function updateTotal()
    {
        var grandTotal = 0;
        var totalItems = @ViewBag.Count;

        for( var counter = 0; counter < totalItems ; counter++)
        { 
            var str = $("[id*=product-total-" + (counter+1)).html();
            var res = parseFloat(str.substring(1,str.length));
            alert(res);
            //alert($("[id*=product-total-" + (counter+1)).html());
            grandTotal = grandTotal + res;//parseFloat($("[id*=product-total-" + counter).html());
            alert(grandTotal); 
        };
        $("[id*=sub-total]").html("$" + grandTotal.toFixed(2));
    }

</script>
```

The value of the .innerhtml is updating once it exits the second function.

Comment: `$.get` and `$.post` are asynchronous. Doesn't really help to invoke `undateTotal` right away, as there is no data anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `updateTotal` from within your callback instead of at the end of the `refreshTotal` function, which initiates an AJAX request. Calling `updateTotal` before the callback runs means that there is no new total to update, and then the callback fires without updating the total. If `updateTotal` is called after the new data is received it will act on that new data.

```
function refreshTotal(ProductId) {
    var qty = document.getElementById("product-quantity-" + ProductId).value;
    var UnitPrice = document.getElementById("unit-price-" + ProductId).innerText;
    var total = qty * UnitPrice;
    $.get('@Url.Action("getItemPositionCart","Home")' , {id: ProductId}, function(data) //data - holds the data returned by the action
    {
        document.getElementById("product-total-" + data).innerHTML = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
        updateTotal(); // moved from end of refreshTotal
        setTimeout(performExpensiveCalculationsAndRender(), 0);
    });

    $.post('@Url.Action("EditQuantity", "Home")', { id: ProductId, quantity: qty }, function (data) {

        updateTotal(); // may need to be included here depending on the action
    }) 

}
```